# Submit a form to a specific function in a php file

Tags: php, forms, function

So I have a form in `index.php`

```
  <? requireonce("action.php"); ?>
  <form action="action.php" method="post">
    //stuff
  </form>
```

I also have a function to handle that form in `action.php`

```
<? 
   function formHandle(){
      //stuff
   }
?>
```

How do I pass the form to `formHandle()` entirely within `index.php`? I don't want to call `formHandle()` in `action.php` because it's required in `index.php` - and I don't want it to run upon page opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so  in `action.php`

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['myform'])){

formHandle();  // call to a function
}

?>
```

Comment: Ahh, so it will only run if the form is actually posted. Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot submit "to a function". Browsers don't care about server-side languages. Browsers communicate via HTTP. HTTP has no concept of "functions" or specific programming languages. You submit something to a URL, and the server handles whatever happens at that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to index.php and call `formHandle` from within index.php.

```
<? require_once("action.php"); ?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    //stuff
</form>
```